# NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android

Trying to read and parse some json data in my app. I implemented Parser class extending AsyncTask as follows:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private String strUrl;
    private List<NameValuePair> params;
    private String result;
    private String response;
    public static final String RESULT_SUCCESS = "success";
    public static final String RESULT_FAILED = "failed";

    public JSONParser(String strUrl, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        this.strUrl = strUrl;
        this.params = params;
    }

    private void parse() {
        try {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(strUrl);

            // Add parameters
            if (params != null) {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // return by response
            result = RESULT_SUCCESS;
            this.response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = RESULT_FAILED;
            this.response = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        parse();
        return response;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }
}
```

It works well in later android versions, but unfortunately it throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in older versions.
I've searched and found that I should use Strict mode in my app, but performance of threads became very bad! when I click parse button it freezes!
can you help me with more better solution?

Comment: How do you initialize the JSONParser? Which methods do you call? Ill give you a hint. It's not `new JSONParser(strurl, params).execute();`

Comment: JsonParser parser = new JsonParser(strUrl, params);
parser.doInBackground();

Comment: @MahmoudElshamy ''Never'' explicity invoke doInBackground(). It's not supposed to be manually called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call you class like this, it will solve your issue !!

```
new JSONParser().execute();
```